# R Shiny : adjust height of DT datatable when fillContainer=TRUE,

Tags: css, r, shiny, datatables

In my R Shiny app, I have a DT datable that has too much columns for the available horizontal space of the container. I therefore use `fillContainer=TRUE` so that the table fits in its container and can be scrolled horizontally and vertically.

My problem is that doing so, only 2 rows are visible simultaneously, even though I have plenty of vertical space available on screen. A reproducible example is given below :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(dataTableOutput("DT")),
    mainPanel()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
data<-mtcars
output$DT<-renderDT(
  datatable(
    data,
    fillContainer=TRUE))
}
 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Do you have tips to easily increase the number of rows visible in the table for more readability independently of other elements that might be present in the app ? Of course, the `height` argument of `datatable` does not respond because `fillContainer=TRUE`. Aren't there any option other than having to fiddle with CSS or HTML to fix the height of the container (if so, how ?) ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using `scrollX = TRUE` instead of `fillContainer = TRUE` along with a given number of rows to show (`pageLength`) or a given table height (`scrollY` = *some css unit*)

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

data <- mtcars

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(DTOutput("DT")), mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$DT <- renderDT({datatable(data, options = list(scrollX = TRUE, pageLength = 15L))}) # alternative: scrollY = "80vh"
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another less elegant way to do it is using fluidrow and wellPanel, to make a nicer box. Also, removing fillContainer=TRUE. You can adjust the width of the siderbar change the number of column (until 12).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  fluidRow(
    column(8,
           div(
             h4("Check Data"),
             wellPanel(
               id = "wellPanelId1",
               dataTableOutput("DT"),
               style = "height:auto; overflow-y: scroll;"
               )
           )
    )
  ),
  
  mainPanel()
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data<-mtcars
  output$DT<-renderDT(
    datatable(
      data))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]